# ἔερθαι: valid verb form? What verb?

Tags: greek, verbs, sappho

This is l. 28 (the last line) of P.Sapph. Obbink:

[image]

I read it as:

> ΝΘ̣€Ρ+ . . +Ι̣

where the uncertain theta could be an epsilon (Obbink reads €̣) and the pluses denote a blank spot in the papyrus, thus equivalent to a lacuna, but not due to a hole in the papyrus AFAICT. I am pretty sure I saw ἔερθαι or something like that (perhaps ἔερθε) somewhere, so I go ahead and complete:

> ]ν ἔ̣ερ+θα+ι̣.

But, there is a problem: I cannot for the life of me find a citation form for this supposed verb. Perseus gives nothing for εερθαι, ερθαι, ηρθαι, and my dictionary has nothing that suggests this form as far as I could find yesterday. The closest thing I can find is αἴρω > ἀέρθαι, but that alpha would probably not turn to an epsilon in Sappho (by whom the poems on the papyrus are), and I even found a contraction of this to ἆρθαι in the line Οὔδεν ἄδομ' ἔπαρθ' ἄγα[ν ἐπ' ὄλβῳ (aka Οὔδεν ἄδομ' ἔπερθα γᾶ[ς ἔοισα if you're reading Campbell), found in [this poem](http://michelegorini.blogspot.com/2018/01/i-wish-to-visit-underworld.html). So is this actually a valid Greek verb form, or did I dream of seeing it? And if the former, what is the dictionary form of this verb? And is this an aorist infinitive as I would guess from the -αι at the end? What voice (active, middle, passive)?

**Note**

When I say "somewhere", I'm not implying it should be in something related to this poem, or even to Sappho. In fact, my vague memory suggests Iliad or Odyssey. I ruled out the former by searching each and every book of it as present on [Greek Wikisource](https://el.wikisource.org/wiki/%CE%99%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%AC%CF%82/%CE%A9) for ερθ and coming back with loads of ύπερθε (with or without prefixes) and other irrelevant words, and Googling έρθ on `site:el.wikisource.org` and not finding anything from Homer. Googling [ἔερθαι](https://www.google.it/search?q=%E1%BC%94%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B8%CE%B1%CE%B9&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=RorKWrC6DefBXs2mvNAO) returns no results, and Googling [ἔερθε](https://www.google.it/search?client=firefox-b&dcr=0&ei=RorKWvyQF9CdkwWL-rWQCQ&q=%E1%BC%94%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B8%CE%B5&oq=%E1%BC%94%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B8%CE%B5&gs_l=psy-ab.3...58911128.58911128.0.58911286.1.1.0.0.0.0.76.76.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.I2MpVJ7ENF4) returns stuff I have yet to browse through.

Comment: I think the best first step would be to locate whatever source supplies "ἔερθαι." [This one](https://newsappho.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/zpe-189-obbink.pdf), which seems pretty comprehensive, just has "νεερ."

Comment: @brianpck I do not know of any source that fills that hole. The only source I have is _The Newest Sappho_, by Anton Bieri and André Lardinois, which contains as its chapter 1 the article _The Newest Sappho: Text, Apparatus Criticus, and Translation_ by Obbink himself. And that also only has νε̣ερ . [.]αι̣. As for the extra vestiges around the pseudohole, I suspect it's because of the dark margins of the pseudohole itself.

Comment: I completely agree with @brianpck . The correct practice is to fill gaps either with known words or with hitherto unattested words with a plausible justification. Postulating -θα- here is as arbitrary as any other guess. All seems to point to your having dreamt of ἔερθαι.

Comment: In our time and age, there is a quick way to check this - TGL http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/index.php

Comment: @AlexB Pardon my ignorance, but what is that site and how do I use it?

Comment: @MickG Set up an account and find out! The wonders of the TLG are manifold and marvellous :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given I couldn't find ἔερθαι or ἔερθε via Google nor on [the TLG](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/index.php), and the commenters have no miraculous ideas as of now, I must conclude I imagined this form. Too bad.

Supposing this is a verb form, the ending -αι is likely. Starting from εερ . αι, one can feed in μ, σ, τ, getting ἔερμαι, ἔερσαι, ἔερται. These are the singular indicative perfect middle-passive of εἴρω, respectively first, second, and third person. This verb means "to fasten in rows" or "to say" or "to ask".

Comment: And indeed ἐέρθαι is the Epic infinitive corresponding to ἔερμαι. ἔερθαι would be its recessively accented Aeolic counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is [ἐέρσαι](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%E1%BC%90%E1%BD%B3%CF%81s%CE%B1%CE%B9&la=greek#lexicon), which I guess is pronounced like ἐέρθαι if you have a lisp.

Less likely, but If the theta was definitely there, perhaps you forgot a nu and were remembering ἔνερθε(ν)? I doubt it, because it's such a common word that one would hardly forget, but I figure I'd mention it anyway just in case.

Meanwhile, ἐέρσαι is found only in the *Iliad* at 14.351:

> τῷ ἔνι λεξάσθην, ἐπὶ δὲ νεφέλην ἕσσαντο
> καλὴν χρυσείην: στιλπναὶ δ᾽ ἀπέπιπτον **ἔερσαι**.

Comment: The theta and alpha are completely lost to a blanked region of the papyrus. The final letter is a vertical line, so almost certainly an iota, though there is a depression in the papyrus to its left which could have been the diagonal stroke of an N, so a nu with its left leg on the edge of the blank is also possible. Eerthai was just something that came up in my mind. @NickNicholas comments my answer saying it's "the Epic infinitive corresponding to ἔερμαι", which I assume is also what eersai is? Or is that the plural of eersa "dew"? You can see the image of this line in the question, btw.

Comment: @MickG I was thinking more in the sense that since εερθαι is unattested, what might you actually have come across in Homer. That's why I thought of ἐέρσαι. And yes, it is the plural of ἐέρση.